# Compile JellyBean's Keyboard for ICS Rom

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, 4.1-jelly-bean, keyboard, custom-roms, device-firmware

I tried creating an Image with a JellyBean's LatinIME.apk, replacing ICS's LatinIME.apk, in system apps folder of ICS ROM, but it crashed. But when I put it in `preInstalledApk` folder, it got compiled and ran successfully.

But it needs to be selected from "Language and Input" in Settings and also both the keyboards have same name.

What I want is to install JellyBean's LatinIME.apk during compile time of Image and also be the default input method. I don't mind if its not a system app. And I will change the ICS's LatinIME.apk-Keyboard name from the code, so that user can selected any of them without scratching their heads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I literally had to scavenge the code up and down to get to the solution. A xml called defaults.xml contains the default input method node. That needed to be changed to the package name of the JellyBean's LatinIME. This is yet to be tested; will let you all know if it runs okay.

---

Edit:
This worked. Please go ahead and get cracking.

Comment: What was the outcome? Can you update this answer?

Comment: Yes, this worked.

Comment: please update the answer, then. It will be better for future users looking into the questions.